# Create new object of class or use static method?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

I have a simple program consisting of 3 classes. GUI, Driver and Main.

Main Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
GUI theGUI = new GUI();
}
```

GUI Class:

```
public void makeGUI(){
final GUI guiInstance = new GUI();
//some other code here
}
```

Instead of creating two objects, can I just make the makeGUI() method static, so I can just avoid creating one unnecessary object? I know for a program of this scale, the performance doesn't really matter, but is it good programming practice to try and avoid unnecessary objects?

Comment: Yes. That's called a factory method, and it's reasonable and common. (Guava uses it for most of its objects).

Comment: It's definitely not good to make unnecessary objects. From your code, it's difficult to see what those unnecessary objects would be

Answer (score 1):

There are two main patterns that would help you here.  The first is [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) and is probably the most straightforward for what you are doing.  The idea is that you only create each object once and then have static methods to fetch the object. In your example the GUI Class may look like this:

```
public class GUI{
    private static final GUI instance = new GUI();

    //Make constructor private so that no one can create an instance
    private GUI(){}

    public GUI getInstance(){
        return instance();
    }

    ... other code
}
```

There are other ways to create singletons but this is probably the simplest.

The other pattern is called the [factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) pattern.  This is similar to singleton but can allow you more control over the number of instances and how the instances are created.  This is probably overkill for what you are doing.

When you really want to go down the path of keeping instances down and have more flexibility you want to start looking into [Dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and frameworks such as spring.

Answer (score 0):

Its interesting how this small question really has many big solutions depending on the context.  The bigger the applications you work on, the more of an issue this is.  Especially when you get into unit-testing and swapping implementations.  Essentially your code will not have many if any `new` calls.

This may be solved with the following in order of increased complexity...

1)  Factory methods.  [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html)

2)  Builders.  [example](https://jlordiales.me/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/)

3)  Singleton.  [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html)

4)  Dependency Injection or Inversion of Control.  [example](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html)

5)  Service locator.  [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/service_locator_pattern.htm)

6)  Web services.  Why create a new object when you can use a service instead.  [example](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#list-gists)

Comment: @Alan thank you.  updated with new link to better example.